# why can't I use if x == "T" x == " " to replace T

Tags: python, list, replace

I want to write a function, replacing T by space.

```
   b=""
   xs=list("fghtThjchk")
   for x in xs:
       if x=="T" or "t":
           x==" "
           b=b+x
```

I can do it with .replace, but I still want to know can I use list to do it.

Answer (score 6):

`x==" "` isn't the same as `x=" "` which is why b is getting the wrong value

`if x=="T" or "t":` doesn't mean "is x one of 'T' or 't'". You need to say it like this `if x in 'Tt':` or this `if x=="T" or x=="t":`

Perhaps this is what you are trying to do

```
b = ""
for x in "fghtThjchk":
    if x == "T" or x == "t":
        x = " "
    b = b + x
```

Answer (score 5):

This line doesn't do what you want

```
if x=="T" or "t":
```

That condition always evaluates to true, because `"t"` is considered truthy.

You mean

```
if x=="T" or x=="t":
```

And the line that says

```
x==" "
```

was meant, I guess, to be an assignment and not a comparison:

```
x=" "
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you are using is little bit incorrect.
The correct way of using if/else in list comprehensions is given below:

`''.join([' ' if x=='T' or x=='t' else x for x in xs])`

-- This method is littler faster & optimized when the string is of large length.

-- We are creating string objects again & again in above answers, which is not recommended.

-- So always use *join()* to join the list after performing all the operations on it instead of *string concatenation* in loops.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of the `re` (Regular Expression) module, which is fast:

```
import re
aa = re.sub(r'([.tT])', " ", "fghtThjchk")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the list by index, such as this:

```
for i, x in enumerate(xs):
    if x in ["T", "t"]:
        xs[i] = " "
```

Comment: This was my first thought, then I saw they are building the new string in `b`

Answer (score 0):

When you do `for x in xs` you're assigning the name `x` to each element of `xs` one at a time. When you do `x=" "` (I presume `==` was a typo) you're reassigning the name `x` but not changing the original element in `xs`.